# Move 1000 Files To Folders, Each 100 to 1 Folder Batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-processing

The idea is moving Files to Folders Like :

The Files Names:

```
1.pdf,2.pdf,3.pdf.....1000.pdf
```

And the results have to be:

```
(1.pdf-100.pdf) To Folder 1
(101.pdf-200.pdf) To Folder 2
(201.pdf-300.pdf) To Folder 3
..
```

This Code is working but it start with (0) and not (1)

```
    @echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for %%a in (*.pdf) do (
    echo %%~na|FINDSTR /R /C:"^[0-9]*$" >nul 2>nul&&(
        set /a NumBas=%%~na/1000*1000
        set /a NumHaut=^(%%~na/1000*1000^)+999
        echo %%~a -^> !NumBas!-!NumHaut!
        IF NOT EXIST "!NumBas!-!NumHaut!" MD "!NumBas!-!NumHaut!"
        MOVE /Y "%%~a" "!NumBas!-!NumHaut!\%%~a" >nul
    )
)
```

Comment: You have to subtract 1 from the file's number while you're doing the math and then add 1 back after the math.  Something like `set /a numbas=^(%%~na-1^)/1000*1000` then `set /a numhaut=^(^(%%~na-1^)/1000*1000^)+1000`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simpler:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for %%a in (*.pdf) do (
   set /A "Num=(%%~Na-1)/100+1, NumBas=(Num-1)*100+1, NumHaut=Num*100"
   IF NOT EXIST "!NumBas!-!NumHaut!" MD "!NumBas!-!NumHaut!"
   MOVE /Y "%%~a" "!NumBas!-!NumHaut!\%%~a" >nul
)
```

If you want folders with simpler "Folder 1", "Folder 2", etc names, just use `"Folder !Num!"` and eliminate NumBas and NumHaut variables.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that your calculation is not working is because the CLI does not support floating points.

When you are doing:

> set /a NumBas=%%~na/1000*1000

you are getting a decimal value. I suspect you are trying to take advantage of this in order to try to round the value.  Unfortunately this doesn't work because as soon as you do **1/1000** it is **0.0001** which becomes **0**, which is why your NumBas is becoming zero when passed to the next command.

I also noticed that you're dividing and multiplying by 1000, instead of 100.  dividing by 100 will result (once corrected) in your files being sorted into thousands:

```
1-1000
1001-2000
2001-3000
```

and not into 100s as you asked in your question, to correct that just change the 1000s to 100s.

Now on the floating point, The easiest way to fix this would be to check if the **NumBas** value is **less than 1**, and if it is, make it **1**

```
IF !NumBas! LSS 1 Set /a NumBas +=1
```

This adjusted code should result in what you're looking for:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for %%a in (*.txt) do (
    echo %%~na|FINDSTR /R /C:"^[0-9]*$" >nul 2>nul&&(
        set /a NumBas=%%~na/100*100
        IF !NumBas! LSS 1 Set /a NumBas +=1
        set /a NumHaut=!NumBas!+99
        echo %%~a -^> !NumBas!-!NumHaut!
        IF NOT EXIST "!NumBas!-!NumHaut!" MD "!NumBas!-!NumHaut!"
        MOVE /Y "%%~a" "!NumBas!-!NumHaut!\%%~a" >nul
    )
)
```

Comment: it works a little bit the first folder begin with 1 but to 99 and the second folder ( 100 to 199) . Thank you for explain the problem

Comment: @IsmailAMANI, It should be making it 1-100, since it is setting the value of NumBas to 1, then NumHaut is 1+99 = 100.  The next number should be 101-200.  I'm glad you found the answer helpful.  Don't forget to mark an answer.

Comment: I understand ! Thank you so Much